# IPN Listener & Log File Permissions

Tags: paypal, listener, paypal-ipn

Our website is on a shared server and we can change file and directory permissions using cPanel.  What are the recommended permissions for the IPN Listener and the IPN Log file?

Currently, they are both set to "0644".  However, the Log text file can be viewed through a web browser if you know the URL, which can't be good.  I don't see any recommendations on PayPal for this.

I did see an older post that mentioned 0755 for the Listener.  Is this still recommended?

Answer (score 0):

File permissions generally don't correlate with whether people can access your files through the web. Permissions only relate to what users and programs *on the local server* can access the file how.

The ideal permissions would be the minimum required for the web server to serve the file, and for you to be able to upload/edit it.

644 is very common I think, but because it's a shared server, I'd check with the server administrator for the optimal setting.

If you have a log text file that you don't want to be viewed through the web, the safest way is definitely to place it outside the web root.